# R data - Combine two rows based on a single similar column within a dataset

Tags: r, plyr

I think this will be relatively elementary, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Imagine a dataset in which there are 108 rows, made up of two readings for 54 clones. Pretty much, I need to condense a dataset based on clone (column 2), by averaging the cells from [6:653], whilst keeping the information for column 1, 2, 3, 654 (which is identical for these columns between the two readings).

I have a pretty small dataset, in which I have 108 rows, and 654 columns, which i would like to whittle down to a smaller dataset. Now, the rows consist of 54 different tree clones (column 2), each with two readings (column 4) (54 * 2 = 108). I would like to average the two readings for each clone, reducing my dataset to 54 rows. Just FYI, the first 5 columns are characters, the next 648 are numeric. I would like to remove columns 4 and 5 from the new dataset, leaving a dataset of 54x652, but this is optional.

I believe that a (plyr) function or something will do the trick, but i can't make it work. I've tried a bunch of things, but it just won't play ball.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're question is to general in the sense that you're not providing any example to work on. Probably that's why people are not answering. Never the less I try to answer you're question.

Answer (score 0):

For average you can use `mean` for leaving out a row or column just subtract the row.

Example:

```
 table[-x,  ] - deletes the x row
 table[  ,-x] - deletes the x column
 (x can be one number or x<-c(1:3) # the first three rows/columns)
```

If you provide more information I think others will also help.